# Weird error on syntax when using SimpleXMLElement::xpath()

Tags: php, simplexml

So, I have a bit of code that goes like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $configuration_path . $this->configuration_file );

// some stuff in between, not important

// next line would be line 80, where the parser whines
$this->ping_tree_1 = ( string ) (( $xml->xpath( '//ping-tree[@order="1"]' ))[0] );
```

Now, it seems valid enough to me, but I keep getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in models/site_configuration.php on line 80
```

If I comment out the offending line(s) and do a:

```
print_r( $xml->xpath( '//ping-tree[@order="1"]' ));
die;
```

I see the following being returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [order] => 1
                )

            [0] => dd0d7afa2414fc1d3ddc18c87351478f
        )

)
```

Which is exactly what I expected.

What is even *more* interesting, though, is that when I do this:

```
$_xml = $xml->xpath( '//ping-tree[@order="1"]' );
$this->ping_tree_1 = ( string ) $_xml[0];
```

Everything works *just fine*!

So... what gives? Anybody got a clue? Is this a PHP parsing bug, or just me being dense?

By the way, this is all on PHP/5.2.17 under Apache/2.2.22 (Unix).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the manual page on arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable
```

You're trying to use this code:

```
$this->ping_tree_1 = ( string ) (( $xml->xpath( '//ping-tree[@order="1"]' ))[0] );
```

The syntax you're trying to use was introduced in 5.4, and you're using 5.2. You've already seen that you can get around this with a temporary variable; your alternative is to update to a later version of PHP.